# Can I Pass Dynamic Value When Calling Flutter Widget Like In React?

Tags: flutter, dart

My background is javascript developer, and in React/React Native you can dynamically pass the props to the component, whether you use it or not within that component. And also you can destructure that passed props in that widget.

For example

```
<InputComponent
   disabled
   ...someOtherAttribute
   dynamicProps={{
      color: 'red',
      isNeedValidation: true,
   }}
/>
```

and then lets say in `InputComponent` you can do something like...

```
const InputComponent = (props) => {
    return (
         <Input 
             disabled={props.disabled}
             {...props.dynamicProps}
         />
    )
}
```

I am curious whether if there is any way to do the same approach in flutter? or is it strict to what has been defined in the widget's constructor?

If it is possible, how to do that?

Comment: Yes, why not....

Comment: Do you have any clue how to do that? @OMiShah

Comment: You always can pass around a `Map<String, dynamic>` if you really want.  That would give up static type checks, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Any widget in Flutter is just a Dart Class. And it's possible to declare and pass any property to Dart class. For example you can have:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> props;

  MyWidget({this.props});

  void readProps() {
    print(this.props);
  }
}
```